# SAPUI5 Fragment close clears the data on previous screen

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am facing a problem in SAPUI5 closing of fragment.
I am creating a fragment and displaying a PDF file. But when I close the fragment, it closes perfectly but clears the data on previous screen from where the fragment was raised.

```
onMenuNavToTerms: function (oEvent) {

        this._sValidPath = sap.ui.require.toUrl("demo/smartapp/pdf") + "/TC.pdf";
        if (!this._onPdfDiag) {
            this._onPdfDiag = sap.ui.xmlfragment("pdfDisplayFragment", "demo.smartapp.view.DisplayPdf", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._onPdfDiag);
        }
        this._oModel = new JSONModel({
            Source: this._sValidPath,
            Title: "Terms and Conditions",
            Height: "600px"
        });

        this.getView().setModel(this._oModel);
        this._onPdfDiag.open();
    },
```

The Above Code opens the fragment and display the PDF. Now the below code shows how I close the fragment:

```
    onPdfCancelPressed: function (oEvent) {
        // var oView = this.getView();
        var oView = this.getView();
        this._onPdfDiag.close();
        this._onPdfDiag.destroy();
    },
```

Once the fragment is closed, the data on the previous screen from where the fragment was opened is cleared.

I would really appreciate help.

Thanks

Comment: Don't destroy it. You already have the logic to create it once if it already exists (`if (!this._onPdfDiag) {`).

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for your reply. Even If I remove the destroy thing It still removes  the data from the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the model like this:

```
   this.getView().setModel(this._oModel);
```

you are overriding the whole application unnamed model! Try to use a different named model for the fragment data or use the method [`JSONModel.setData(oData, bMerge?)`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel%23methods/setData): if you set `bMerge` to true the new data are merged with the older model data.